# Physical Model Clarification

Tags: database-design, data-modeling

I am learning Database Design/Modeling and I have a concern. While researching conceptual, logical, and physical data models, I found the following source which outlines what makes up each model and provides examples of each: https://www.1keydata.com/datawarehousing/data-modeling-levels.html

To create data models, I use Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler. According to the following article, the physical model is made up of Data Definition Language statements that create the tables that make up a database: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280883225_USING_SQL_DEVELOPER_DATA_MODELER_AND_MICROSOFT_ACCESS_FOR_TEACHING_DATABASE_MODELING_AND_DESIGN

This definition varies greatly from the definition in the original web page. The logical models look fairly similar, but the physical model definition is nowhere close.

Which source is more accurate? Is there something that I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The industry flouts basic principles as it sees fit and abuses any terminology for purposes of marketing its own toolset if such abuse is deemed helpful to get the sales figures up.  If in the user community, for one reason or other suddenly foobars become a hot thing, you can bet your ass all vendors set their engineers and technical writers to finding a way to "validly" claim that their toolset supports foobars.  Even if they didn't change a single byte of code of the toolset to achieve that.

So just don't believe anything you get from a vendor except when it relates directly to the actual operation of one of his products.

Here are a few examples of the consequences :

Graphical db design tools such as the one you mention, but it's certainly not the only one, typically muddle "conceptual" and "logical" in that rectangles get mapped to tables automatically.  Not absolutely necessary and it influences (limits !) the way the "conceptual" part can be used by imposing rules that actually pertain to the logical part (the fact that there is a table in the system).

Each and every SQL engine muddles the "logical" and the "physical" because basically no engine allows, e.g., CREATE TABLE statements that leave out all the physical stuff such as INDEXes, or if it does it won't be a very good idea to use it in that way anyway.